# Mysql Latest record comparison

Tags: mysql

I am working with a system where a cron job runs daily to check for memberships activated on that date and then check orders table if the query has run in that month for that particular membership, if not, then it charges the customer for that month.
I have setup the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6dbd3/1) for my schema.

This is the query I currently have

```
SELECT * 
FROM membership m
JOIN paymenttokeninfo pt ON pt.customerid = m.customerid
JOIN orders o ON o.membershipid = m.id
WHERE DAY(m.membershipdate) = DAY('2020-01-05')
AND m.active = 'Y'
AND m.chargeable = 'Y'
AND pt.isactive = 'Y'
AND pt.token <> ''
AND MONTH(o.orderdate) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

The issue is that I am not understanding how to resolve orders table part.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.id,m.membershipdate,m.customerid  -- add other columns as needed
FROM membership m
JOIN paymenttokeninfo pt ON pt.customerid = m.customerid
WHERE DAY(m.membershipdate) = DAY('2020-01-05')
AND m.active = 'Y'
AND m.chargeable = 'Y'
AND pt.isactive = 'Y'
AND pt.token <> ''
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM orders o WHERE o.membershipid = m.id
   AND MONTH(o.orderdate) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
```